# Forward ftp.domain.com to AWS EC2 URL

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was setting up my EC2 as my ftp server as found here:
https://gist.github.com/gunjanpatel/37d306cd1585ece1179b

Everything works but my servername is 
xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com

and I want it to be ftp.domain.com.

I allready have my domain bought and running itself with an a-record setting route53 so www.domain.com is routing to my S3 bucket allready,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [Amazon manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html) how to change the hostname of Amazon Linux

> For Amazon Linux 2: Use the hostnamectl command to set your hostname
>   to reflect the fully qualified domain name (such as
>   webserver.mydomain.com).
>
> ```
> [ec2-user ~]$ sudo hostnamectl set-hostname webserver.mydomain.com
> ```
>
> Reboot the instance to pick up the new hostname.
>
> ```
> [ec2-user ~]$ sudo reboot
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can reboot using the Amazon EC2 console (on the
>   Instances page, choose Actions, Instance State, Reboot).

Comment: Thx, but how would that work without routing from ftp.domain.com to the server? I mean dont I have to set the dns itself (route 53)?

Comment: You should set new A record there also with the IP of the machine

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I allways get the message "The record set could not be saved because:
- Alias Target contains an invalid value."

Comment: Please update your questions. Also some snapshot can be helpful (how do you set those records for example)